# Incluir codigo html en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy trabajando en una app ASP.NET MVC, en el cual en el Front cargo un datatable.net por medio de un JSON el problema es que en cada row me debe agregar el icono de editar y eliminar.

[image: datatable.net]

El código que ocupo es el siguiente:

HTML y JavaScript

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table id="clientes" class="table table-hover display">
            <thead style="background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; color: #fff;">
                <tr>
                    <td>ClienteId</td>
                    <td>Razón Social</td>
                    <td>Número Documento</td>
                    <td>Dirección</td>
                    <td>Fijo</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Estado</td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="celda">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clientes").DataTable({
            "language": {
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "sUrl": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            },
            ajax: {
            "url": "@Url.Action("ListaClientes")",
        "dataSrc": ''
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "ClienteId" },
            { "data": "RazonSocial" },
            { "data": "NumeroDocumento" },
            { "data": "Direccion" },
            { "data": "Fijo" },
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "Estado" }
        ]
        });
    });
```

El detalle es que en cada row debe ir el botón de editar y eliminar, ¿será posible de poner código HTML en el JavaScript que tengo para poblar el datatable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sería necesario agregar la propiedad `columnDefs`. Por ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> ('+ row[0]+')';
                },
                "targets": 2
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>            
</table>
```

---

Para tu caso sería:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> ('+ row[0]+')';
        },
        "targets": 7
    },
    {
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> ('+ row[0]+')';
        },
        "targets": 8
    }   
]
```

*PD. Los nùmeros que están entre paréntesis son para que puedas ver como capturar el valor del id, por ejemplo.*

---

**Referencia:**

- [Column rendering](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Comment: Hola row se refiere a la fila, cuando le de click a uno de los botones me tomara el id, pero ese código es referencial, por que así como esta me sale un mensaje en ambos botones que dice (undefined).